# Sample Xamarin.Forms Project Without Using XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, code-behind, sample

Late to the party and new to Xamarin.Forms.  I'm looking for an example Xamarin.Forms app (sample code) which does not use any XAML, or, as little as possible.  This is because I'm translating from an existing C# project where all of the user interface elements are built in code.

The existing project has two what would be called "forms": a splash form, and an application form.  The structure of the application form changes dynamically - for example, depending on the GPS coordinates of the user at start-up, hence the dynamic building of the form.

The two "forms" exist as independent classes extending ContentPage and using AbsoluteLayout.  My difficulty boils down to how to get the splash screen to display at start-up, and then, after determining what my application form should look like and establishing its structure, hiding the splash form and showing the application form.

The building of the splash and application interfaces already take into account scaling for display size and orientation.

We have googled around a fair bit on this end but apparently we're not googling the right thing.

Comment: all of the Xamarin docs contains code samples in both XAML and C#.  Why don't you post a specific example of what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Idea: its easier to find answers that use xaml. It might be easier to take these steps: **1)** Get a "simplified" (NOT dynamic) version working with XAML. **2)** Attempt to translate xaml to c#, by taking each xaml element, and looking up doc page for it. Should be a c# code snippet example there. **3)** If you get stuck, post the working xaml, and the incomplete c#, and describe what you are stuck on. **4)** NOW make it dynamic. BOTTOM LINE: the "dynamic" changes to UI will be easier to get working once you've mastered the xaml to c# conversion steps, for a "not dynamic" version of the forms.